# browser plug-ins in java based browser

Tags: java, browser

I have a Java Browser and want it to use plugins like a flash-plugin within it (similar to the plugin functions in Firefox).
How can I do so?

Comment: Rephrase, please? I'm not understanding what problem it is you want an answer to.

Comment: `plug-ins in java` what do you mean exactly here ?

Comment: What are plugins for browsers? You mean something like add-ons for firefox?

Comment: I mean that a can a java browser use a flash player plug-ins .We know that fire-fox can use adobe flash player . I also mean the add-ons .

Answer (score 0):

You cannot write browser plugins in Java. Don't try.

Answer (score 0):

Provided that your browser *supports* plugins, whether it's written in Java, HeadFuck or plain old Haskell, you should be able to tell it how to recognize flash content, and give it the necessary wrapper functions to your plugged-in renderer.

So you'll need to carefully read two pieces of documentation: that of your browser, and that of the target renderer.

Unless we get more info on exactly what browser you're talking about, and about what plugin your talking about, there's not much more to say...

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the JEditorPane is to process "text/html" which is the default, "text/plain", and "text/rtf". JEditorPane is mostly used for displaying HTML. The RTF support is not too complete.

Many people expect a self made browser based on JEditorPane to be able to execute JavaScript, which is not the case. You could do that with the [Lobo Project](http://lobobrowser.org/java-browser.jsp) though. Lobo browser allows you to use [plug-ins](http://lobobrowser.org/browser/plugin.jsp) too. I reckon that a Flash plug-in would be fairly complicated to create.

Take also a look at the Mozilla Widget for Java Swing [MozSwing](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mozswing/).